# how to set the orientation of ili9325 lcd display

Tags: c, driver, stm32, avr, lcd

I want to change the orientation of contents on ili9325 display. according to the datasheet I should change the AM and ID0 and ID1 registers to change the orientation of GRAM data. but when I change these registers and display some data on the LCD, it won't change the orientation.

[datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/ILI9325.pdf)

Comment: Please describe the problem a bit more specifically by linking datasheets and providing code snippets.

Comment: this is the data sheet :[link](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/ILI9325.pdf) my problem is that when I change the AM and ID0 and ID1, the orientation won't change. the datasheet describes how to change the orientation by Changing ID0 and ID1 and AM. I'm using stm32f103 fsmc to control the lcd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually an *init* problem.

When you initialize these LCDs in a wrong way, sometimes they won't work correctly. So, check your initialization process and then rotate the lcd again. that should work. (read the initialization process from the datasheet)